# "Running out of colors" error when creating black masks for images

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm trying to create a distractor set and I'm doing that with this for loop:

```
for mask in input_images:
    img = Image.open(path + mask)
    print(mask)

    width = img.size[0]
    height = img.size[1]

    for i in range(0, width):  # process all pixels
        for j in range(0, height):
            data = img.getpixel((i, j))
            img.putpixel((i, j), (0, 0, 0))

    img.save(masks_path + '/' + mask[:-4] + '.png')
    print(masks_path + '/' + mask[:-4] + '.png saved!')
```

It basically takes every image, converts the pixel of every image to black, and makes a copy of it. But this is the error it's throwing after a while:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/onur/PycharmProjects/masking-image/main.py", line 24, in <module>
    img.putpixel((i, j), (0, 0, 0))
  File "/home/onur/PycharmProjects/masking-image/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1794, in putpixel
    value = self.palette.getcolor(value, self)
  File "/home/onur/PycharmProjects/masking-image/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PIL/ImagePalette.py", line 143, in getcolor
    raise ValueError("cannot allocate more than 256 colors") from e
ValueError: cannot allocate more than 256 colors
```

I don't understand why I'm getting this. I am only referencing one color, which is black. Is there a quicker way to make purely black copies of images?

Comment: "*Is there a quicker way to make purely black copies of the images?*" [numpy.zeros_like](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.zeros_like.html)

Comment: @Bilal How can I simply apply np.zeros to this? Can you show a demo?

Comment: congrats. the error says you have a palette image and I'd guess that it doesn't already have an entry for black in the palette, so it fails on the first attempt to set a pixel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea why you would want to fill an image with black, but here's a way to do it:

```
from PIL import Image

# Load original image and convert to greyscale to save space
im = Image.open('input.png').convert('L')

# Fill with black
im.paste(0, box=(0,0,*im.size))
```

---

Another way to do it is with a point processing function that makes each pixel zero:

```
# Make greyscale and set all pixels equal to zero
im = im.convert('L').point(lambda i: 0)
```

Comment: What are you multiplying `*im.size` with?

Comment: Also, some images are completely transparent

Comment: The `*` is unpacking the 2 elements of the `size` tuple into a width and a height - it is not multiplying anything. It is making a 4-tuple from two zeroes and a 2-tuple. See here https://treyhunner.com/2018/10/asterisks-in-python-what-they-are-and-how-to-use-them/

Comment: They cannot be transparent if you converted them to `L` mode like I showed.

Comment: I'll make that more explicit in my answer.